# Possible to have a variable inside a range property?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to pass a variable into the .range property?

I would like the following function to work, but I can't seem to get it to work. My guess is it is something to do with how I'm calling the range property.

```
function computeNVEndTime()
Dim lastTime As Range
Dim totalTimes As Integer
Dim prod As New ProductionWebObj
dim ws as WorkSheet

set ws = ActiveSheet
totalTimes = prod.FindNumberOfRanges("time")
Set lastTime = ws.Range("time_" & totalTimes)

If isEmptyString(lastTime) Then
    computeNVEndTime = ""
Else: computeNVEndTime = lastTime.Value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Is "time_(n)" in a group of named ranges?

Comment: Yes. ws.Range("time_10") is what lastTime should be set to, if I knew how to pass a variable into the .Range property.

Comment: If `totalTimes` has the value 10 then your code should work provided the named range exists on that sheet.

Comment: Put a break on line `totalTimes = ` and bring up the Locals window, to see what the value is of totalTimes.

Comment: It appears that totalTimes was returning 0 instead of 10, like I expected. The named ranges were not on the "ActiveSheet," but the next sheet over. Thanks for your help @TimWilliams and @peege!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that totalTimes was returning 0 instead of 10, like I expected. The named ranges were not on the "ActiveSheet," but the next sheet over. Thanks for your help @TimWilliams and @peege!